# Is it possible to run a SQL Query with incrementing date?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query

```
SELECT MIN(SUBSTR(START_TIME,12,15)), MAX(SUBSTR(END_TIME,12,15))
FROM JOBS_HISTORY2
WHERE ORDER_DATE = 20190904
```

I am currently running this and changing the order_date manually by incrementing it by one and copying over the result. Is there a way where its possible to modify the query so it runs it for all remaining days? 
such as 20190905, 20190906 etc. I tried the following; I thought about putting all the dates in a list and using 'IN' but are there better ways that are more effective?

This is oracle sql developer

Comment: Are you storing dates as strings here?

Comment: For this to be answerable, you would probably need to provide sample data and expected results.

Comment: Is `order_date` a number rather than a date?  What does "all remaining days" mean?  Do you just want `order_date >= 20190904` (assuming `order_date` is a number rather than a date)?

Comment: Yes dates are stored as varchar and it looks like 20190816 for 08/16/2019. Its a date but the structure just looks like that format. Remaining days mean till now as in that date is august 16th so all the dates till today 12/10/2019 so 20190816 until 20191210 im sure its impossible, but I thought i'd ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you just want `GROUP BY`?

```
SELECT ORDER_DATE, MIN(SUBSTR(START_TIME,12,15)), MAX(SUBSTR(END_TIME,12,15))
FROM JOBS_HISTORY2
WHERE ORDER_DATE >= 20190904
GROUP BY ORDER_DATE
ORDER BY ORDER_DATE;
```

Comment: Yes SIR this is exactly it! thank you so much. I feel so silly... I'll accept your answer in 2 minutes thank you!